# How to install OpenCL to Vega 8 mobile graphics card on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, opencl, amd-gpu, davinci-resolve

I'm trying to use DaVinci Resolve on my Linux laptop (Huawei MateBook D15) Ryzen 5 3500U and a Vega 8 graphics card. It gives an error that no OpenCL GPUs are found. After some research I found that I needed to download those drivers from AMD. But there is no Linux driver for Vega 8 graphics card. So then I found [this website](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html#ubuntu) and a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efKjfBkjPlM) for it.

I followed the steps in the video. In when installing the terminal  asked me to put in a secure boot password. I did it but after reboot, I still couldn't launch DaVinci Resolve. Then I disabled the secure boot in my BIOS, and installed again, but it still didn't work.

I don't know what else to try, I'm still a beginner to Linux, and maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

There are no drivers for this model in Linux, I also had problems in many distributions